# AddHandler In htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, parsing, file-extension

I have some custom file types I am using that are just plain text and I need them to be parsed through a PHP file (for example reader.php) and then displayed to the user. I have been reading about AddHandler in .htaccess, but I can not figure out how to make this work. I send my file type (lets say .foo) to reader.php, but I can't figure out how to get reader.php to take that as input. Any suggestions?
My AddHandler code in .htaccess:

```
Action foo-handler /foo/reader.php
AddHandler foo-handler .foo
```

Comment: Is the handler not running, or some message in the error.log, or no trace of the original request in `$_SERVER[]`?

Comment: @mario It seems when I forward the request to the interpreter, the interpreter acts like it didn't receive anything. No error log. Nothing.

Comment: In any case, RewriteRules interact more reliably with however PHPs handler is setup (might be a handler itself, or a ProxyPassMatch for FPM).